# Need help creating specific shape in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, path

I wanted to create a square shape with a curvature on one side but do not know how, using Path

[Example image shape I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFPiK.png)

The closest I could ever came to is this shape

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red" Data="M50,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100 L0,30 A30,30 0 0 1 30,0 Z" Margin="-886.5,-3741.5,1414.5,5143.5" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw it like this:

```
<Path Fill="Teal"
      Data="M0,0 L100,0 100,100 50,100 A50,50 0 0 0 0,50Z"/>
```

For details of the parameters of the `A` directive, see [`ArcSegment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.arcsegment?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) and [Path Markup Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). The main difference to your approach is the value of the `sweepDirectionFlag`.